# есть массив объектов, необходимо его отфильтровать

Tags: javascript

```
 const persons = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 24,
        position: "senior",
        isActive: false,
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        age: 33,
        position: "middle",
        isActive: false,
    },
    {
        name: "Sam",
        age: 29,
        position: "junior",
        isActive: true,
    }
]

let filterData = (arr, obj) => arr.filter((person) => person.age === obj.age || person.position === obj.position)
let res = filterData(persons, {age: 24 });
console.log(res)
```

есть массив данных, его необходимо отфильтровать.
если я пишу через оператор || то все работает.
но если я добавляю второй параметр для поиска:

```
filterData(data, {age: 24, position: "junior" });
```

то фильтр забирает объекты и по возрасту и по позиции. срабатывает оператор ||.
суть задачи в том чтобы проверялись оба критерия. можно это реализовать совместив метод filter и every, но я не могу понять как их правильно вместе написать. объясните пожалуйста. непонятен алгоритм написания. ключи для поиска могут быть любыми из перечисленных в объекте

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте по алгебру логики (Булеву алгебру) и про логические операторы JavaScript. Вам нужно использовать вместо логического "ИЛИ", тот самый оператор ||, логическое объединение "И", для этого есть оператор &&.

```
person.age === obj.age && person.position === obj.position
```

UPD: Соответственно следует проверять в функции наличие ключей для фильтрации, раз стоит такая задача, вот реализация:

```
function filterData (arr, obj) {
    return arr.filter((person) => {
        const age = obj.age ? person.age === obj.age : true;
        const position = obj.position ? person.position === obj.position : true;
        return age && position;
    });
}
```

Здесь в коллбэк функции фильтарции теперь выполняются проверки на то, имеются ли значения для возраста и для должности, если ключа нет, то это условие становится true, чтобы корректно выполнялось логическое "И".

Полный код выглядит так:

```
const persons = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 29,
    position: "senior"
  },
  {
    name: "Sandy",
    age: 24,
    position: "senior"
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 22,
    position: "middle"
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 19,
    position: "junior"
  }
]

function filterData (arr, obj) {
    return arr.filter((person) => {
        const age = obj.age ? person.age === obj.age : true;
        const position = obj.position ? person.position === obj.position : true;
        return age && position;
    });
}
let res = filterData(persons, {age: 19 });
console.log(res)

let res2 = filterData(persons, {age: 24, position: 'senior'});
```

Comment: так я пробовал, но тогда не работает с одним ключом для поиска, и я не могу знать какой ключ введет пользователь. но при использовании every внутри filter я могу решить эту проблему, но я не пойму как их вместе записать

Comment: @Den, по-видимому, потому что нужно проверять во время фильтрации наличие ключей. Дополню ответ

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) можно получить массив хранящий в себе ключи и значения, далее с помощью метода [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) можно проверить, удовлетворяются ли все они определенному условию

```js
const persons = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 29,
    position: "senior"
  },
  {
    name: "Sandy",
    age: 24,
    position: "senior"
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 22,
    position: "middle"
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 19,
    position: "junior"
  }
]

function filterData(arr, obj) {
  const conditions = Object.entries(obj);
  return arr.filter((person) => conditions.every(([key, val]) => person[key] === val));
}
let res = filterData(persons, {
  age: 19
});
console.log(res)

let res2 = filterData(persons, {
  age: 24,
  position: 'senior'
});
```